# How do I swap the places of an int in java?

Tags: java, algorithm

I need to swap places of an int. For example, if I call for the method swapDigitPairs(482596), it will return me 845269. The 9 and 6 are swapped, as are the 2 and 5, and the 4 and 8.

If the number contains an odd number of digits, leave the leftmost digit in its original place. For example, the call of swapDigitPairs(1234567) would return 1325476. I'm not suppose to solve using a string and I should use a while loop to solve it. I'm not supposed to use any arrays.

Below is what I have done so far. But I am stuck at the swapping position and I know I need to multiply by the places(like tenth,thousand etc) depending on the number.But I am stuck at this part. What I have done is to retrieve the number one by one.

```
public static int swapDigitPairs(int number) {

    while(number!=0) {
        int firstDigit = number%10;

        for(int i =10;i<=;i*=10) {
            int secondDigit= firstDigit*i;
        }

        int leftOverDigit = number/10;

        number=leftOverDigit;

    }
    return number;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: what about doing your homework?

Comment: I am stuck at the part where i need to swap the places of the int.

Comment: Since you are not allowed to use string or array you will have to do with subtraction and addition.

Comment: There is no way this isn't homework. (If so, please add the homework tag.)

Comment: To remove digit `x` from `n-th` position (i.e. to put zero there) you need to subtract `x*10**(n-1)` (x multiplied by 10 to the (n-1)th power. Then you can put a new value in a similar fashion.  Or you can both steps at once by adding (y-x) and (x-y) accordingly.

Comment: @esej the [homework tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework) has been deprecated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the solution (tested):

```
public static int swapDigitPairs(int number) {
    int result = 0;
    int place = 1;
    while (number > 9) {
        result += place * 10 * (number % 10);
        number /= 10;
        result += place * (number % 10);
        number /= 10;
        place *= 100;
    }
    return result + place * number;
}
```

The key points here are:

- the loop consumes digits from the right hand side of the number, so the odd/even processing distinction is gracefully handled
- the terminating condition is that there are at least two digits remaining
- loop logic deals with two digits per iteration
- use the remainder operator `%` with 10 (ie `number % 10`) to produce the last digit
- integer division by 10 numerically truncates the last digit
- there is no need to hold the last digit in a variable - it just clutters the code

---

Here's some tests and some edge cases:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(swapDigitPairs(482596));
    System.out.println(swapDigitPairs(1234567));
    System.out.println(swapDigitPairs(12));
    System.out.println(swapDigitPairs(1));
    System.out.println(swapDigitPairs(0));
}
```

Output:

```
845269
1325476
21
1
0
```

Comment: Great answer, but I'd do the while inline, like ```for (; number >= 10; number /= 100, place *= 100) result += place * (number % 10 * 10 + number % 100 / 10);```

Comment: why is the while loop condition >9?

Comment: @JuanLopes I would code it as a `for` loop in preference too, but the question clearly stated that a `while` loop must be used.

Comment: @user2135654 the loop should only iterate if there are at least two digits remaining, thus the test for `> 9`

Comment: oh so meaning to say that the loop will start from 10? and i will do the result twice in the loop because its for the 2 numbers?

Comment: The loop doesn't "start" from anything, rather the loop will only be *executed* if the number is at least 10. That's because if number is a single digit, which eventually happens if there's an odd number of digits, you want to leave the loop (or in the case of a single-digit input not enter the loop at all).

Answer (score 2):

If you have `abcdef`

Then `((a+b)*10000 + (c+d)*100 + (e+f)) * 11 - abcdef = badcfe`

Comment: And If the number contains an **odd** number of digits we can easily subtract the left most digit away, do your stuff and then add it back.

Comment: @user2135654 Because 2 digits each segment.

Answer (score 2):

a simple solution is

```
    int i1 = 482596;
    char[] a = String.valueOf(i1).toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i += 2) {
        char tmp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[i + 1];
        a[i + 1] = tmp;
    }
    int i2 = Integer.parseInt(new String(a));
```

Comment: OP is not allowed to use String or Arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code with some test cases

```
public class ReverseNumberDigit {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(reverseNumber(123456789));
        System.out.println(reverseNumber(12345678));
        System.out.println(reverseNumber(1234567));
        System.out.println(reverseNumber(123456));
        System.out.println(reverseNumber(12345));
        System.out.println(reverseNumber(1234));
        System.out.println(reverseNumber(123));
        System.out.println(reverseNumber(12));
        System.out.println(reverseNumber(1));

    }

    private static int reverseNumber(int orinalNumber) {
        int reverseNumber = 0;
        int x = 1;

        while(orinalNumber > 9){
        int lastNumber = orinalNumber %  10; 
        orinalNumber = orinalNumber / 10;
        int secondNumber = orinalNumber %  10;
        orinalNumber = orinalNumber / 10;
        reverseNumber = reverseNumber + (lastNumber * x * 10) + (secondNumber * x);
        x = x * 100;
        }
        if(orinalNumber > 0){
            reverseNumber = reverseNumber + orinalNumber * x;
        }
        return reverseNumber;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Java, but this might be another solution;

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DigitsPlaceSwap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DigitsPlaceSwap demo = new DigitsPlaceSwap();

        System.out.print("Enter a whole number : ");
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = stdin.nextInt();
        
        demo.switchDigits( number );
    }

    public void switchDigits( int number ) {
        int getDigits = 0;
        int numberOfDigits = String.valueOf(number).length();
        String result = "";

        for( int i = 1; i <= numberOfDigits; i++) {
            getDigits = ( ( number % (int) Math.pow( 10, i ) ) / (int) Math.pow( 10, i - 1 ) );
            result += Integer.toString( getDigits );
        }

        System.out.println( "Swapped Number is : " + result );
    }
}
```

It doesn't validate the input if it's a positive whole number in the range or not. I convert it to a String to make it print zeros on the left after swapped.

```
Enter a whole number : 342325400
Swapped Number is : 004523243
```